# need to add multiple markers using custom google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i was checking out the google map api to integrate in my website.
made this page with what ever i could understand so far.

everything is working fine but there is just one thing, that i want three markers on the same map.
when i am adding more than one markers then the map stops working.

test link : http://goo.gl/X9q92s

you will have a better understanding if u see my link. 
this is the code that i got from google map api.
 and i edited it to get grey scale map with my desired marker box.
i just want to add two more....

Please help.

```
   <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: In your code you're only adding one marker.  Update your question to show us the code you're using to try and add three markers.

Comment: Hi Duncan, i added code for one more marker...please help...

Comment: Define _'map stops working'_.  The only thing I spot obviously wrong here is you create a new variable for your second infowindow, `infowindow1`, but then you don't use it, and instead re-use `infowindow` in the click event handler for `marker1`

Comment: ... also you overwrite `styledMapOptions`, which you only use the second time.  And also `mapOptions`, which you only use the first time.

Comment: it means that the map marker is not showing. even if i am using the same event handler, shouldnt it atleast show the second marker?

Comment: hi duncan, i think should use mapOptions only once and i removed the styledMapOptions also.

Comment: Hi duncan....forget thsi code...can u help me with this 10 line code...this code is short because it had got no css styling and additional code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your "new marker" code into its own function, like so:

```
function LoadMarkers(name, lat, lng) {
            var MarkerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var MarkerOption = { map: map, position: MarkerLatLng, title: name};
            var Marker = new google.maps.Marker(MarkerOption);
}
```

Putting this into its own function allows you to "refresh" the markers with ease, by simply invoking the function with a timer or some other event. A program I'm working on refreshes the map every few seconds, as my data source is constantly changing with new/removed/updated records that should be reflected immediately on the map. I think this is a great way to do this.

Then, in your program, you can create a loop that shoots the information for each marker in by invoking the LoadMarkers function. I've recently fallen in love with SqlDataReader.

Your loop would iterate through a SqlDataReader and each record read will invoke the script like so:

```
InvokeScript("LoadMarkers", New Object() {name, lat, lng})
```

This is a great moment to also add an InfoWindow for each marker.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{
content: "Content here"
});
```

As well as a click listener for the InfoWindows. ;)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function () {
                typeof infoWindowsOpenCurrently !== 'undefined' && infoWindowsOpenCurrently.close(); //If there is an InfoWindow currently open, close it
                infowindow.open(map, Marker); //Open a new one for the selected marker
                infoWindowsOpenCurrently = infowindow; //Set the new info window to the temporary variable
            });
```

Some might not like this method of using a loop. I like it because I can "personalize" each marker for each record, while personalizing each of their InfoWindows too. In my code above, assume that "name" is a unique ID that lets you specify a specific marker for later use, such as identifying which marker was clicked and which InfoWindow is currently open.